# How to access the sum of values ​of an object built based on a constructor function

Tags: javascript

I am building a rpg character builder and first of all I am doing the logic in javascript. Each character has 10 points to distribute in their characteristics and choose advantages.

**Character Constructor**

```
function personagem(frc, hab, res, arm, pdf) {
    this.frc = frc;
    this.hab = hab;
    this.res = res;
    this.arm = arm;
    this.pdf = pdf;
}
```

**Building a Character**

```
var eu = new personagem()
eu.frc = 1
eu.hab = 1
eu.res = 1
eu.arm = 1
eu.pdf = 1
eu.PV = eu.res * 5
eu.PM = eu.res * 5
```

I managed to make a function that adds all the numbers of the characteristics to check if they do not exceed the limit, but how do I get the cost of the advantages (vantagem.cost) to apply in that same function and see if the cost has been exceeded with the characteristics?

And how apply the bonus (For example, the Aceleração advantage adds +1 hab to the character)

**Function with total points**

```
var total = () => {
    return eu.frc + eu.hab + eu.res + eu.arm + eu.pdf
}

const totalofPoints = () => {
    if (total() > 10) {
        console.log("You have exceeded the number of points")
    } else {
        console.log("You Did it!")
    }
}

totalofPoints()
```

**Advantages Consctructor**

Assuming my character has these two advantages, how could I access the sum of them and add the first bonus

```
function vantagem(nome, custo, bonus) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.custo = custo;
    this.bonus = bonus
}

Example of Advantages
var aceleracao = new vantagem("Aceleração", 1, eu.hab + 1)
var adaptador = new vantagem("Aceleração", 1)
```

Comment: why don't you use modern JS objects ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

Comment: What would be the advantage of this method in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think well about your structure. You currently have two components in your system: A **Character** and an **Advantage**. The character is probably the main component of the two, where the advantage only adds something to the character, like a plugin.

Give your character a method to add an advantage to a character. In that function calculate the bonus given by the advantage to the character.

I could not fully understand what some things in your code meant as they were in Spanish, so I tried to make a prototype based on what you tried to make.

First the function for creating an advantage. This function should indicate what *property* of the character it should adjust, and the values for the cost and bonus.

```
/**
 * Advantage constructor
 *
 * @param {string} name Name of advantage.
 * @param {string} stat Name of stat property.
 * @param {number} cost Cost of advantage.
 * @param {number} [bonus=0] Bonus added to character.
 */
function Advantage(name, stat, cost, bonus = 0) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stat = stat;
  this.cost = cost;
  this.bonus = bonus;
}
```

The Character needs a way to get advantages. So I've created a method called `addAdvantage` which takes an advantage and counts is up to the current stats.

```
/**
 * Character constructor
 *
 * @param {string} name Name of the character.
 */
function Character(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stats = {
    agility: 1,
    dexterity: 1,
    strength: 1,
    speed: 1
  };
  this.life = 5;
  this.mana = 5;
  this.advantages = [];
  this.pointsToSpend = 10;
}

/**
 * Add a value to a single stat of the character and calculates
 * the remaining points to spend
 *
 * @param {string} stat Stat to add value to.
 * @param {number} value Value to increase stat with.
 */
Character.prototype.addStats = function(stat, value) {
  if (this.stats[stat] !== undefined && this.pointsToSpend - value > 0) {
    if (stat === 'strength') {
      this.life += (value * 5);
    } else if (stat === 'dexterity') {
      this.mana += (value * 5);
    }
    this.stats[stat] += value;
    this.pointsToSpend -= value;
  }
}

/**
 * Add an advantage to the character and calculates the advantage
 * on top of the previous stats.
 *
 * @param {Advantage} advantage An Advantage instance.
 */
Character.prototype.addAdvantage = function(advantage) {
  if (advantage instanceof Advantage) {
    let { stat, cost, bonus } = advantage;
    if (this.stats[stat] !== undefined && this.pointsToSpend - cost > 0) {
      if (stat === 'strength') {
        this.life += (bonus * 5);
      } else if (stat === 'dexterity') {
        this.mana += (bonus * 5);
      }
      this.stats[stat] += bonus;
      this.pointsToSpend -= cost;
      this.advantages.push(advantage);
    }
  }
}
```

Then put it all together by first creating the character, then creating the advantages and finally adding the advantages to the character with the `addAdvantage` method.

```
// Create the character.
const geralt = new Character('Geralt');

// Add stats to the character.
geralt.addStats('speed', 2);
geralt.addStats('strength', 3);

// Create advantages.
const agilityBoost = new Advantage('Agility Boost', 'agility', 1, 2);
const powerfulDexterityBoost = new Advantage('Powerful Dexterity Boost', 'dexterity', 2, 3);

// Add advantages to the character.
geralt.addAdvantage(agilityBoost);
geralt.addAdvantage(powerfulDexterityBoost);
```

Below is a snippet where it's all put together so you can try it out.
Small note: Functions that are supposed to be used with the `new` operator should start with a capital letter. This makes it obvious for the user how use this code.

```js
function Advantage(name, stat, cost, bonus = 0) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stat = stat;
  this.cost = cost;
  this.bonus = bonus;
}

function Character(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stats = {
    agility: 1,
    dexterity: 1,
    strength: 1,
    speed: 1
  };
  this.life = 5;
  this.mana = 5;
  this.advantages = [];
  this.pointsToSpend = 10;
}

Character.prototype.addStats = function(stat, value) {
  if (this.stats[stat] !== undefined && this.pointsToSpend - value > 0) {
    if (stat === 'strength') {
      this.life += (value * 5);
    } else if (stat === 'dexterity') {
      this.mana += (value * 5);
    }
    this.stats[stat] += value;
    this.pointsToSpend -= value;
  }
}

Character.prototype.addAdvantage = function(advantage) {
  if (advantage instanceof Advantage) {
    let { stat, cost, bonus } = advantage;
    if (this.stats[stat] !== undefined && this.pointsToSpend - cost > 0) {
      if (stat === 'strength') {
        this.life += (bonus * 5);
      } else if (stat === 'dexterity') {
        this.mana += (bonus * 5);
      }
      this.stats[stat] += bonus;
      this.pointsToSpend -= cost;
      this.advantages.push(advantage);
    }
  }
}

const geralt = new Character('Geralt');
geralt.addStats('speed', 2);
geralt.addStats('strength', 3);

const agilityBoost = new Advantage('Agility Boost', 'agility', 1, 2);
const powerfulDexterityBoost = new Advantage('Powerful Dexterity Boost', 'dexterity', 2, 3);
geralt.addAdvantage(agilityBoost);
geralt.addAdvantage(powerfulDexterityBoost);

console.log(geralt);
```

Comment: OH thank you! im going study your code now, but what is @param inside comments

Comment: One thing I'm having trouble with your code is adding a second AddStats, because I wanted to create a "life" property that is 5 times another property, because I can't just do it

Character.prototype.addStats2 = function (name, value) {
    if (this.pointsToSpend - value> 0) {
        this.stats [name] + = this.stats [name];
    }
}

Comment: `@param` is a part of [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) where you can tell in the comments what the argument of a function can and should be. Editors like VSCode will pick this up and show this when you hover over the function in your code. So basically it's instructions for everyone using your code.

Comment: Instead of creating a new `addStats` method, try modifying the existing one. Check what `stat` is being added and based on that, make a calculation on how much life or mana, or whatever you want has to be added. Also, steer clear of function names like `addStats2`. If you look back on your code in a month you will totally be forgotten what it's for. Instead give it a name that describes what your code does.